# why my Query is too Slow sql server 2005

Tags: sql-server-2005

I've two table serialNumber, Org

```
create table org(
  org_id  INT NOT NULL IDENTITY(1,1)PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED,
  orgName VARCHAR(10)
  )
create table serialNumber(id  INT NOT NULL IDENTITY(1,1)PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED,
                          org_id INT FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES org,
                          serialNumber BIGINT,
                          transferedStatus INT DEFAULT(0),
                          parentID INT NULL FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES serialNumber)

insert into org values('ORG A')
insert into org values('ORG B')
insert into org values('ORG C')
insert into org values('ORG D')
insert into org values('ORG E')

insert into serialNumber values(1,123456100,0,NULL)
insert into serialNumber values(1,123456101,0,NULL)
insert into serialNumber values(1,123456102,0,NULL)
insert into serialNumber values(1,123456103,0,NULL)
insert into serialNumber values(1,123456104,0,NULL)
insert into serialNumber values(1,123456105,0,NULL)
```

I want transfer  serialNumber (123456100) from ORG A to ORG B and mark 
          it as transfered 
          transferedStatus = 0 (in stock)
          transferedStatus = 1 (out of stock)

here is my query it's work but its too slow when I want transfer a huge number of serialNumber (10K) ... I know there is other's way to do it but how ?!

```
declare @parentID int
declare @From_org_id  int 
declare @To_org_id  int 
declare @serialNumber BIGINT

set  @From_org_id  = 1
set  @To_org_id  = 2
set @serialNumber = 123456101

/* mark the serialNumber as transfered */

UPDATE serialNumber                             
set
transferedStatus = 1 
Where   
org_id              = @From_org_id
AND serialNumber    = @serialNumber 

/* find ID of the source of Serial Number */
select TOP 1 @parentID = id
FROM serialNumber
Where org_id            = @From_org_id 
  AND transferedStatus  = 1
    AND serialNumber    = @serialNumber 
ORDER BY id DESC


insert into serialNumber values(@To_org_id,@serialNumber,0,@parentID)
```

[sqlfiddle LINK](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/85226/10)

Comment: What kind of indices do you have on your tables?

Comment: two indices   1  : NONCLUSTERED(org_id asc,serialNumber asc) 2: NONCLUSTERED(org_id asc,transferedStatus asc,serialNumber asc)

Answer (score 1):

You're doing it row by row, so no wonder it's slow for 10k rows. Try modifying your procedure so that it works on table value parameter instead of int. Example of tbv usage:
http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2008/08/31/sql-server-table-valued-parameters-in-sql-server-2008/
Set-based operations will certainly be faster.

Comment: Yes it work for sql server 2008, but I'm using sqlServer 2005 .