# what's wrong with my sql script? (sql server)

Tags: sql-server, performance, sql-server-2005

my table serialNumber, Org 
  I want transfer  serialNumber (123456100) from ORG A to ORG B and mark 
          it as transfered 
          transferedStatus = 0 (in stock)
          transferedStatus = 1 (out of stock)

here is my query it's work but its too slow when I want transfer a huge number of serialNumber (10K) ... I know there is other's way to do it but how ?!

```
create table org(
  org_id  INT NOT NULL IDENTITY(1,1)PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED,
  orgName VARCHAR(10)
  )
create table serialNumber(id  INT NOT NULL IDENTITY(1,1)PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED,
                          org_id INT FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES org,
                          serialNumber BIGINT,
                          transferedStatus INT DEFAULT(0),
                          parentID INT NULL FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES serialNumber)

insert into org values('ORG A')
insert into org values('ORG B')
insert into org values('ORG C')
insert into org values('ORG D')
insert into org values('ORG E')

insert into serialNumber values(1,123456100,0,NULL)
insert into serialNumber values(1,123456101,0,NULL)
insert into serialNumber values(1,123456102,0,NULL)
insert into serialNumber values(1,123456103,0,NULL)
insert into serialNumber values(1,123456104,0,NULL)
insert into serialNumber values(1,123456105,0,NULL)





declare @parentID int
declare @From_org_id  int 
declare @To_org_id  int 
declare @serialNumber BIGINT

set  @From_org_id  = 1
set  @To_org_id  = 2
set @serialNumber = 123456101

/* mark the serialNumber as transfered */

UPDATE serialNumber                             
set
transferedStatus = 1 
Where   
org_id              = @From_org_id
AND serialNumber    = @serialNumber 

/* find ID of the source of Serial Number */
select TOP 1 @parentID = id
FROM serialNumber
Where org_id            = @From_org_id 
  AND transferedStatus  = 1
    AND serialNumber    = @serialNumber 
ORDER BY id DESC


insert into serialNumber values(@To_org_id,@serialNumber,0,@parentID)
```

[sqlfiddle LINK](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/85226/10)

Comment: possible duplicate of [why my Query is too Slow sql server 2005](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15612064/why-my-query-is-too-slow-sql-server-2005)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're likely not doing individual inserts for your Inserts, probably more for example, but this is more efficient for large amounts of inserts:

```
insert into #serialNumber 
values
(1,123456100,0,NULL)
,(1,123456101,0,NULL)
,(1,123456102,0,NULL)
,(1,123456103,0,NULL)
,(1,123456104,0,NULL)
,(1,123456105,0,NULL)
```

Next, for your actual update, give this a run, using the OUTPUT clause we can do the update and insert in one swoop, saving a few lookups, which could be costly.

```
UPDATE serialNumber                             
    set transferedStatus = 1 
OUTPUT @To_Org_id, INSERTED.serialNumber, 0, INSERTED.Id  into serialNumber
Where   
    org_id = @From_org_id
    AND serialNumber    = @serialNumber
```

Comment: thanks for you reply, The question is, what is the best way to insert a hug number of serial number ( by exemple FROM 12300000 to 12310000), I m using loop while() { insert...}(php) inserting row by row ...

Comment: Are you asking about the initial insert into the SerialNumber table or the transfer. Your original question asks both.

Comment: the initial insert into SerialNumber

Comment: Using the method I show above using one select and multiple value lines, is more efficient that issuing individual insert statement for each line.

Comment: I realy don't see how, I'm using php with sqlServer 2005

Comment: Are you asking about Sql performance, which was your original question or are you asking how to use Sql with PHP?  I'm not sure I understand your requirements at this point

Comment: So, I'm using php with sql to insert those serial Number, but it's too slow when I insert a huge number like 10K of serial Number, I only want the best way to do an insert, yes you helped me a lot for transfer with your script

Comment: You might want to start that as a seperate question and tag the PHP guys as mine is very rusty and I'd rather not send you down the wrong road.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, when you insert large amount of data in table which have raised indexes, that might slow down your insert batch.

Disable clustered index on table `serialNumber` and try again. If you had more indexes, disable them all, insert your data, and rebuild indexes. Rebuilding indexes will enable them all.

Comment: 10K Rows really isn't a lot for an index, something of that size might not even use the index, so this suggestion might be more work than its worth.